# missing font in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

```
<head>
<link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

**fonts.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: opensans-regular;
    src: url(fonts/opensans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: fontico;
    src: url(fonts/fontico.ttf);
}
```

`fontico` is my own font, created with CorelDraw.

There is no problem with `Chrome` and `Opera`.

In `Firefox` - `opensans` is there, but `fontico` is missing.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do double check the src. Other than `ttf` format is accepted in firefox.

**Extra**:  Please have the habit of using Web Fonts, [here](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-web-fonts-getting/) is the best article to understand the use of web fonts. You can convert the ttf to web fonts using Online Web Font Generators like [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Comment: thanks a lot. After converting it on `fontsquirrel` it works. What is the difference, pls?

Comment: Please check this article.  https://css-tricks.com/understanding-web-fonts-getting/

Answer (score 0):

After check..

Did you already tried using in connection with ' format("truetype")' after the src?

Independently I would recommend to use not only truetype, but also types like *eot* and *woff*.
Simply increases the availabillity.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "fontico";
    src: url("/fonts/fontico.eot");/* IE9*/
    src: url("https://www.youraddress.com/fonts/fontico.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url("/fonts/fontico.woff2") format("woff2"), /* chrome、firefox */
    url("/fonts/fontico.woff") format("woff"), /* chrome、firefox */
    url("/fonts/fontico.ttf") format("truetype"), /* chrome、firefox、opera、Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
    url("/fonts/fontico.svg#Fontico") format("svg"); /* iOS 4.1- */
}
```

Maybe is one of the fallbacks working better with firefox.